# Is there any server side event triggered when DetailsView cancelButton is clicked?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

When in Insert Mode or Edit Mode of DetailsView, the default behavior of click CancelButton is clear inputs in TextBox. But I just want to redirect to other pages instead of clear inputs. I hope there is server side event triggered so I can Response.Redirect.

Client side (some JS?) redirect is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [ModeChanging Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.modechanging.aspx) and [CancelingEdit Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsviewmodeeventargs.cancelingedit.aspx).

```
void DetailsView_ModeChanging(Object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit ||
        e.NewMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
    {
        if (e.CancelingEdit)
        {
            //canceled
        }
    }
}
```